# Is $k(X)\subset k((X))$ an algebraic extension of fields?

Tags: power-series

Let $k$ be a field, and consider the field $K=k((X))=\text{Frac}(k[[X]])$.
Then there exist a transcendence basis $\mathscr{B}$, i.e., a subset of algebraically independent element of $K$ such that $K\supseteq k(\mathscr{B})$ is an algebraic extension. I was wondering if such a basis should just consist of $X$, but than I do not see how can be $k(X)\subseteq k((X))$ an algebraic extension.
Anybody has a clue about this?

Comment: I’m pretty sure $k((X))$ is never algebraic over $k(X)$. To begin with, if $k$ is countable, then so is the algebraic closure of $k(X)$, whereas $|k((X))|=2^\omega$.

Comment: Q: in this question what does the inner [] brackets in Frac(k( [[X]]) indicate?

Comment: A power series in $\mathbb F_q[[x]]$ is algebraic over $\mathbb F_q(x)$ iff it is automatic, by Christol’s theorem. This overview paper has more interesting information: http://maths.mq.edu.au/~alf/www-centre/alfpapers/a103.pdf .

Answer (score 3):

Certainly not! It is easy to show that $e^X:=\sum \frac{X^n}{n!} $ (I am assuming $\mathrm{char}(k)=0$ here) is not algebraic over $k(X)$. In fact, $k((X))$ is not finitely generated over $k(X)$, so your transcendance basis $\mathscr{B}$ must be infinite.